# A white fungus has started growing on the bark/knots of one of my tree. Anyone know how I can treat it naturally?

Tags: trees, fungus

[image: White tree fungus]

Anyone know how to treat this white fungus on my tree? Would like to save it and treat naturally if possible and avoid having it spread to the rest of the grove.

---

Comment: What kind of tree is it?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: How long has this been on the trunk, has it appeared recently? Is the tree in good health otherwise?

Comment: The tree is going to die, difficult to say how long that will  take . A very small chance the fungus is on the surface and not growing in the wood. and the tree is good.

Comment: related: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/56797/499

Comment: @kevinskio - I'm not convinced this is a bracket or shelf fungus... still  need to know what condition the rest of the tree is in to answer...

Comment: @kevinskio - I agree with Bamboo. When I saw the post's title, I expected to see a shelf fungus or maybe a nasty case of slime flux, but instead saw what looks like an alien growth. I'm very curious to see what the fungus could be.

Answer (score 2):

Blacksmith 37 is right unfortunately. Your tree will die. When fungi appear on the outside of a tree it is because all of the inside has grown an mycelium enough for it to now 'bloom' through to the outside with fruiting bodies (mushrooms: bracket shelf or otherwise) so they can disperse spores. By that point it is hopeless. You may get a few more years, or maybe even several, over which time it will wither and die. Hopefully you can get some interesting edible shrooms in the meantime, like honeys, turkey tails, even oyster, and morels like to grow around them on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what type of fungal infection that is without better pictures and knowing what type of tree it is. A mild way to treat it is mix one tablespoon of baking soda in a liter of water and spray the affected exposed fungal growth. Take pictures before and measurement of size, then make observations and respray after rain or to continue treatment if it looks like the fungi is shrinking.